# Searchbar to search array items and displays them on a tableview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I want to build an app that shows a empty tableview. Then users can write a text on a searchbar and when they click on Search button the tableview will be written with array items founded.

I only need to search when user click SearchButton. How can I do this? What methods do I have to use?

I've tried with this method, but it doesn't works.

```
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {

    NSInteger nVideos = [appDelegate.allVideos count];

    NSLog(@"number of videos: %i", nVideos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you update your datasource that associates with tableView? As far as i can see, once user click search button with some search term, you should update your array that relates to tableView and reload it.